# Enable permissions on a folder to allow file upload.

Tags: php, apache, upload, xampp

I'm using xampp on a mac. I have the following script which I'm trying to use to upload a file to a folder:

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

The upload form is simply:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My folder structure in htdocs is:

```
-/htdocs
  -index.html
  -upload.php
  -/upload
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/dirt.png)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/development/Templates/PHP&JS/Upload
>   Files to Server/form upload/upload.php on line 29
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpAQWDB1' to
>   'upload/dirt.png' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/development/Templates/PHP&JS/Upload
>   Files to Server/form upload/upload.php on line 29 Stored in:
>   upload/dirt.png

How do I change the properties of the upload folder to allow uploading of files? I there a config file I should include to enable this?

Comment: Run `chmod` to set proper permissions on the upload folder. See [this Apache Friends](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=144737) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command

```
chmod -Rf 777 FOLDER_PATH
```

here FOLDER_PATH is the your folder path where the images get stored

Comment: This is a really bad idea in terms of security. I know this is a local environment but it gives a bad example. The issue is certainly that the OWNER of the folder where files are uploaded is now Apache's user (usually *www-data*)

`sudo chown www-data:www-data FOLDER_PATH`
And the permissions can be 700 (safest) or 755 (so you can view the content locally).

Comment: @Tibo I just gave the solution..its upto their wish whether to give 777 or 755 or any other..(based on their requirement)

Comment: I agree with you, I just think that they might not now (or other readers) that there is a security issue here and there's another way to stay safe

Comment: I agree with @Tibo: it's a bad idea. And it's not a solution...it's only a bad workaround. The right answer is that you must give write access to the user that execute the apache process, or to the group that own the folder. For example u can do this: `chown -R your_user:www-data folder/ && find folder/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} + && find folder/ -type d -exec chmod {} + `. Where _your_user_ is in _www-data group_